# Shimano FC-RS500 11 speed chainset with 10 speed cassette and chain

Tags: drivetrain

Is it possible to use a Shimano 11 speed crankset FC-RS500 with a 10 speed ultegra cassette and chain. I will be using 105 5700 front deraileur and a 105 5701 rear. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using shifters that match the derailleurs (i.e 105 5700 series), then yes this will work.

11 speed cranks have a slightly closer chainring spacing than 10 speed to accommodate the narrower chain. Consensus on this site is that you can go one speed difference on the crank and get working front shifting.

I like to point out that the non-series RS500 cranks are somewhat heavier than 105 5700 and I would not call them a great match, but if you are looking for a way to get an affordable compact 110mm BCD crank to work with the rest of the drivetrain it will provide a workable solution.

Comment: Upvoted, but you could/should mention that a common result of this kind of mismatch is you get rub between the chain and the large ring in more small/small combos than you would otherwise, and you can usually fix it such that it works perfectly with thin chainring spacers. (I usually wind up doing it with the .6mm wheels mfg ones, but they're thicker than needed for the purpose.) This can get pretty bad on bikes with short chainstays; to put it in perspective, tri bikes with exceptionally short stays can have a lot of this kind of rub even with the right chain. Not much margin for error.